Image Cache in Flutter
I'm new to Flutter and currently stuck on an image loading problem. In my application I'm querying feed posts from a firebase dataserver, which contain a URL to an image.
When scrolling down new posts are getting loaded and currently the old ones seem to be getting destroyed and need to get downloaded again when scrolling up.
Is there a quick solution to cache the images to reduce bandwith traffic?
Thanks in advance!
This is my code:
class Feed extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<List<Post>>( 
        stream: FeedService().getPosts(), application layer
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
            return Center(child: Text('No posts available'));
          }

          final posts = snapshot.data!;

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: posts.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return PostItem(post: posts[index]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreatePostScreen()),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        heroTag: 'createPostButton'
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PostItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Post post;

  PostItem({required this.post});

  @override
  State<PostItem> createState() => _PostItemState();
}

class _PostItemState extends State<PostItem> {
  bool _isBookmarked = false;
  bool _isLiked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.post.userProfileImageUrl),
            ),
            title: Text(widget.post.username),
            subtitle: Text(widget.post.timestamp.toDate().toString()),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
          ),

        CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: widget.post.imageUrl,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: double.infinity,
          cacheManager: CacheManager(
            Config(
              'customCacheKey',
              stalePeriod: Duration(days: 7),
              maxNrOfCacheObjects: 100,
            ),
          ),
          placeholder: (context, url) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()), 
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error), 
        ),

          // Like and comment section
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _isLiked = !_isLiked;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(_isLiked ? Icons.thumb_up : Icons.thumb_up_outlined),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.comment_outlined),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isBookmarked = !_isBookmarked;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(_isBookmarked ? Icons.bookmark : Icons.bookmark_outline),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),

          // Post caption or text (if needed)
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Text(
              widget.post.description,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Use Cachenetwork image package . it will works fine,
